# Regular Expression for getting single digits

Tags: regex, perl

I have this sample data:

```
    1
    2a
    12
    23a
```

Using regular expressions, I would like to substitute data with single digits into this format:

```
    01
    02a
    12
    23a
```

Any other suggestions would be a big help as well

Comment: post what you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/cK3w5v/2) with multiline `m` flag:

```
(?<!\d)(\d)(?=[a-zA-Z]|$)
```

Then replace with `0\1`.

```
my $str = 'your data'
my $regex = qr/(?<!\d)(\d)(?=[a-zA-Z]|$)/mp;
my $subst = '0\\1';
my $result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rg;
```

- `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind. Match will start only if previous character is not a digit
- `(\d)` is the first group, it matches one digit
- `(?=[a-zA-Z]|$)` ends match if next character is a letter (`[a-zA-Z]`) or line ends has been reached (`$`)
- Substitute `0\1` is the first group (the digit) preceded by zero

Comment: `\1` is only necessary within the regex itself. In the replacement text you should use `$1` instead - `s/(?<!\d)(\d)(?=\D)/0$1/`.